# Angular 17 New Controlflow Syntax error "EOF" in html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17

i Upgraded my Project with ng update and it worked seemlesly. I can use the new Features like @if,@for etc...

1. But my Problem is that my html Code where i use the new Control flow Syntax get this error : Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)ngtsc(-995002). I Mean the Program Compiles but the Error is realy ugly and confusing. Hope u guys cold help me.

I have tried to enter in the tsconfig and updated packages and Languageserver

```
{

  "angularCompilerOptions": {

    ....

    "_enabledBlockTypes": [

      "if", "switch", "for", "defer"

    ]

  }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e86Z.png)

Comment: If you're on v17 proper _enabledBlockTypes isn't required. Include more details, package.json etc

Comment: Hej ive edited my Post. With my package.json hope this would help

Comment: You need to upgrade node to a compatible version. see https://angular.io/guide/versions